# Show correct number of textbox based on input number in another textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, input

I have a textbox with type number. I want to display specific number of textboxes based on the input number of the user. Is it possible that I can do that?
I have my code like this and I still dont have any idea of how can I display textboxes based on the input.

```
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h5> Number of Columns:</h5><input type="number" name="" class="form-control">
 </div>
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. You need code to check the number of the text field. And then code to create that many text boxes. Have you tried writing javascript to do that? We just see your HTML code.

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath I haven't tried yet. I have no idea where to start

Comment: Okay well can you specify your exact requirements? FYI Usually people here want you to try out code yourself first and then get help if you're still stuck. I would suggest breaking down what you want into very specific details. Then it seems javascript would handle all of what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this code work?

```js
function textbox() {
  $('#textboxes').empty();
  var a = document.getElementById("number").value;
  for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    var textbox = document.createElement("textarea");       
    document.getElementById("textboxes").appendChild(textbox);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-5">
    <h5> Number of Columns:</h5><input type="number" name="" id="number" class="form-control" value="0">
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="textbox()" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="textboxes">
    </div>
</div>
```